# How do I generate a 2D Array with values, each with neighbours of different, non-repeating values?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a square 2D Array, which I wish to fill with values between 1 to 4.
For this to be correct, the neighbours of any of the values inside the array would need to look like this, as an example:

```
x 2 x
3 1 1
x 4 x
```

The **x** values are irrelevant to the middle value 1. As we can see, the neighbours of middle value 1 do not appear more than once, aside from itself

An incorrect value's neighbours would look like this:

```
x 2 x
3 1 2
x 4 x
```

One of the neighbours of middle value 1 appear more than once (the value of 2 appears twice), and we don't want this.

I have made a LUA solution for this problem, but it is very slow, as all it does is add 2 rules to the generation and runs through all combinations until it finds a valid one.

The rules being:

1. Corner neighbours (in our case the **x**s) cannot have the same value as the middle value
2. The next value OVER the relevant neighbours cannot have the same value as the middle value.
   Explanation for rule 2:

```
y y y y
y 1 y x
y y y y
```

The **x** in this instance cannot have the value of 1, this applies for every vertical and horizontal direction (up-down-left-right)

EDIT: I now know I can just repeat a tileable pattern, but this is not what I wanted, as I do not want a clear repetition to be observable

Comment: How would this look for a bigger array, say 6x6?

Comment: A correct solution for 6x6 would look like this:
`1 3 4 1 3 3
4 3 2 1 4 2
4 1 2 3 4 1
2 1 4 3 2 1
2 3 4 1 2 4
4 3 2 1 3 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply repeat a pattern to get the desired array.

1. Row 1: `1 2 3 4 1 2 3...` repeated for the required number of columns
2. Row 2: `3 4 1 2 3 4 1...` repeated similarly
3. Row 3: Same as row 2
4. Row 4: Same as row 1
5. Row 5: Start repeating pattern from row 1

...continued for the required number of rows.

Here's an example for a 6x6 grid:

```
1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4
3 4 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 1 2
1 2 3 4 1 2
3 4 1 2 3 4
```

This is guaranteed to follow both rules, since:

1. The diagonal for a value of `x` here will always be `5 - x`, and `x != (5 - x)` for `x in [1,2,3,4]`.
2. The next over value for `1` will always be `3` and vice versa (in any direction), and same for `2` and `4`.

Edit: In your comment, you've mentioned that you needed the array to be more "varied". Any form of randomness would mean that we can't use any patterns. In that case, your current solution can not be improved, since you can't use any pattern for optimisation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, you are right about repeating a pattern, however I wanted for this array to be a little more varied as I was going to use it to generate a map of some sort, and having it clearly repeat over and over is not really what I wanted. Apologies that I did not clarify that in the post.

Comment: @jordan edited the answer to include a comment on the "variety" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Block that if repeated any number of times in any direction does not Break the neigbour-constraint. One such Block (I'm sure there are others, but this is the most trivial I think) would be:

```
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
2 2 1 1
4 4 3 3
```

You can repeat this Block any number of times in any direction and every cell will always have unique neighbors.

For example, if you need a 6x8-array just repeat the Block once to the right and down, and then slice according to the size you want:

```
1 1 2 2  1 1
3 3 4 4  3 3
2 2 1 1  2 2
4 4 3 3  4 4

1 1 2 2  1 1
3 3 4 4  3 3
2 2 1 1  2 2
4 4 3 3  4 4
```

Fun Fact: On further inspection one might recognize, that Abhinav Mathur and I came up with a somewhat similar solution. If you rotate my Block and swap the 2 with the 3, the pattern is the same. But his formulation with repeating rows instead of the whole block is probably easier to implement in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I write this as a second answer as there is a new requirement: Don't use any repeating pattern!

### TLDR

Just fill the array row for row, left to right. With following constraint:

[image]

You want to fill the value x, then you **only** have to consider the values in the colored cells.

1. If the green cell is filled, then there is only one possibility for x (the one value that is not in either the green or red cells)
2. If the green cell is empty (you are at the left border). Then there are two options (one of the values that is not in the red cells). But the value that you choose has to be one of the values in the blue cells too (this is always possible) or otherwise it will be impossible to fill the value y later! If the blue cells aren't filled (right border) you can just ignore this secondary constraint.

### Explanation

You can separate this into two independent problems. Think of your array like a chessboard and solve the numbers in the light and dark fields separately as they don't care about each other (light and dark don't share any neighbors because their neighbors are always of the opposite color respectively).

So you split your chessboard in light and dark (just to better understand, you don't have to actually separate the arrays).

[image]

Then you solve them separately with some simple constraints. The value (green) is not allowed to be equal to one of the values two cells apart (red):

[image]

Just fill the values row by row from left to right. You can only actually choose a value at the left border as the rest will be constrained by the other three values above. At this left border you have to be careful. The chosen value in the green cell has to be the same as one of the values in the blue cells. Otherwise the next cell (red) will be impossible!

[image]

Just do this for the light and dark cells and then put them back together:

[image]

This should be relatively easy to implement and really fast, as it is not brute-forcing anything but directly constructing a valid solution. When saying choose a number or fill values I mean to just get the possible values and choose one at random.

You can try yourself in excel too, it's like a really boring sudoku as there is actually not much to choose, it is really constrained :).

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! It is indeed a solution much closer to what I was looking for, however, I have either failed to implement it correctly, or it just doesn't help much as I still get quite a lot of failed solutions, like this one for example:  
`1 1 3 4 2 3 1 1 2 2  
4 4 2 1 1 4 4 3 3 1  
3 3 2 X 0 0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (x7)`  
As you can see, the value of X is impossible due to the fact that the red cells you mentioned have all the possible values of 1,2,3,4. Please let me know if this is a mistake on my part, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes you're right, unfortunately the second constraint in my TLDR needs to always be followed it seems, if the green cell is empty or not. But if the green cell is not empty there is no choice thus possibly resulting in an impossible state as you've shown. This is difficult, as the problem already surfaced with the 1 in the top-right of the x, at that point it was already doomed. But for that 1 there was no choice either (or would be if there was another row above), so the puzzle can be made impossible quite early which then only manifests at a much later point.

Comment: But the suggestion to separate the problem into two independent problems still stands. If you could modify your software to solve for a valid light solution and a valid dark solution that should already be a significant speed-up. You can then combine any light solution with any dark solution and it should be a valid solution for your full array. The constraint is basically still the same, but you only have to apply your constraint to half as many cells.